# two div position fixed and float without percentage width , but not working in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

i'm Sorry for poor English writing :)
i trying float two div side by side that position is fix, I don't want use percentage for their, this code good show to all browser but ie 6 not working

HTML

```
 <div class="right"></div>
 <div class="top"></div>
 <div class="main">
   <div class="content"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
body{
 margin-top: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
} 
.right{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  z-index: 5;
}
.main{
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  right: 200px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline;
  z-index: 1;
}
.top{
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
  right: 200px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: yellow;
  clear: left;
}
```

Comment: IE6 has marketshare waaaaaaay below 1% - do you *really* need to bother yourself with it?

Comment: Why bothering with IE6 at all? It doesn't understand half of today's standards...

Comment: Alot of businesses still use IE6 on their systems. If the OP is developing something for a business client, you can't cut out potential clients because you don't want to support a browser.

Comment: Alot of businesses still use IE6??? where are you getting those stadistics.

Comment: tnx all , but i would support IE6 for this project :(

Comment: use `table` if you'd like to support IE6. oldies but goldies lol.

Comment: forget IE6, go! save yourself!

Comment: you are not floating the divs, they are positioned absolute

Comment: dear friend i know that , but my client business so that user's until use IE6

Answer (score 0):

IE 6 has a double margin on float issue as explained here: http://www.cssnewbie.com/double-margin-float-bug/#.Uoo6xflgfTQ

add

```
display: inline;
```

to your floated elements to fix that.

However, in your code, i've seen you use both floats and position: fixed so,

you can remove all the floats altogether and it will solve the issue without changing the layout.

Comment: tnx bro but test it, but not working in IE6
screen shot in IE7:
http://s18.postimg.org/kqp2dx72h/Capture.jpg

in IE6:
http://s21.postimg.org/4dovhqhtj/ie6.jpg